# Touch anywhere to continue

Tags: android

how to make such feature?

[image]

I have two ideas, but both do not know how to fully realize.

1) After a certain action to show one layout on top of another(I do not know how to do it and maybe it will not be right because there will be no visible elements of the first layout) and then implement OnClickListener for the second layout.

2) Draw a rectangle on top of the layout, it also I make not right. as I do it: putting in RelativeLayout

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/rectangleIv" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

draw on Activity

```
ShapeDrawable line = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());  
    line.setIntrinsicHeight(200);  
    line.setIntrinsicWidth(150);  
    line.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    image.setBackgroundDrawable(line);
```

but in all RelativeLayout elements the height and width are fill_parent and this rectangle does not cover them and turns out that just changing background color. And the problem is that setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated.

**UPD** solution to the problem by custom dialog

```
protected void showCustomDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

    customDialog = builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null)).create();

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = customDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    lp.dimAmount = 0.4f;

    customDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    customDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom dialog (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) with this design, then set true to `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`
 and `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`

Hope it helps

**UPDATE**:

First create a style in style.xml file with name **CustomDialogTheme** and add the color **TransparentGrey** like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="TransparentGrey">#7F000000</color>
    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/TransparentGrey</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Second create the layout for the dialog (**R.layout.customdialog**):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/iTouchEveryWhere"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- ImageView or TextView with "Touch everywhere to continue..."  -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="false"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then code the dialog like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourCurrentActivity.this,
                R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_fichaarticle);
  dialog.setCancelable(true);
  dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

  RelativeLayout rlTouchEveryWhere = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.iTouchEveryWhere)

  rlTouchEveryWhere.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });      

  dialog.show();
```

Comment: custom dialog it's an interesting way. But the problem is that it hides elements that are in the background

Comment: if you set dimmed dialog, won't hide elements on background: WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount=0.0f; // Dim level. 0.0 - no dim, 1.0 - completely opaque
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

Comment: or if you want to set blur to dialog set: dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

Comment: I updated my post in wich my custom dialog, but neither LayoutParams does not work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Give your Root layout an id in XML like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/root_layout" //relative layout
```

in onCreate of your Activity,

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
```

and set `OnClickListener` to layout.

Comment: I know about OnClickListener for layout, I wrote about it. 
But I don't know how to use it in my case. I certainly can set OnClickListener after certain action (and not in onCreate). But how to make that color of the forward background changed(like in the picture which I attached)